# Laravel submit form with ajax not working inside td tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, laravel-5, html-table

I have a table that displays upcoming tournaments with a 'enter tournament' button in the last td element of each row as shown below.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($tournaments as $tournament)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $tournament->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $tournament->start_time }}</td>
            <td align="right">1</td>
            <td align="right">1</td>
            <td>${{ $tournament->prize }}</td>
            <td>${{ $tournament->entry }}</td>
            <td>
                <form class="entertournament" method="POST" action="{{action('EnterTournamentController@enterTournament')}}">
                      <input type="hidden" name="tournamentid" value="{{ $tournament->id }}">
                      <button class="btn btn-label-success btn-sm btn-upper btn-submit-entertournament">accept</button>&nbsp;
                 </form>
            </td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Below is the javascript used to submit the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $(".btn-submit-entertournament").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                let form = $(this).closest('form');
                console.log(form);
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: form.serialize(),

                    success:function(data){
                        if(data.successful) {
                            toastr.success(data.successful);
                        }
                    }
                });

            });

</script>
```

If I place the form outside of the table the form will submit fine and display the toastr notification that is returned from the controller as expected.

However when placing the form inside the td element I get redirected to /enterTournament when submitting the form and a 419 | page expired error is displayed.

I then include @csrf under the form (even though I think this is strange because I know I have the csrf specified in my head - hence why the form submits fine when it is outside the table).

Now when I try submit the form once again I get redirected to /enterTournament but this time with a JSON response: {"successful":"Tournament entered"}. This is the response that should be displayed through the toastr notification without a page redirect when submitting the form.

Any ideas why this is happening when the form is placed inside a td tag?

UPDATE: If I remove the class from the table element: class="kt-datatable" it is now working as expected. However I need this class to be applied to the table. Seems a bit odd, any ideas on how this class is causing problems for the form submission?

Comment: does this statement `console.log(form);` returns same form when inside and when outside the `<td>`? Also check if you are not nesting the forms. Nesting of form is not supported and can give unexpected results.

Comment: Console.log(form) will return jQuery.fn.init [form.entertournament, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)] when the form is outside the table. When the form is inside the td tag the console returns JSON Formatter: Type "json" to inspect. json
{successful: "Tournament entered"}. I believe it is fine to use a form inside a td element. (Element form is not allowed as child element of tr or table but I am placing the form within the td element.  The code validates without any errors https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: You are absolutely right but I was talking about form inside a form which can happen due to some missing tag. Also if both your `console.log(form);` statement not returning same form object then it can be an issue. Also can you show some more code in which you are creating the forms. are there multiple forms on same page?

Comment: Hi Sainesh, there are no forms nested within each other. Each table row will have 1 form placed in the last td element of each given row so there could potentially be multiple forms on the same page. Each form submits with the given tournament id of that row.

https://ibb.co/RcRZN40

Comment: Here is the expected output when the form is submitted outside the table (toastr notification displayed as expected on same page form was submitted) : https://ibb.co/LJQw0kC

Here is the output when the form is submitted inside the td tag (redirects to /enterTournaments on submit):
https://ibb.co/4jQnnXK

Comment: Just two things: 1) `id="tournamentid"` is inside a loop and should be unique, fix that. 2) I think it's better to listen for `submit` on the form instead of `click` on the button. That way you don't need to find which form it is related. Add a `type="submit"` to the button. Please add the HTML code in the image to the question.

Comment: Yes you are correct about the ID, that wasn't originally part of the code I was trying new fixes since posting the question and forget to remove it again. Adding type="submit" has not changed the output.

Comment: Try changing this line `$(this).closest('form');` to `$(this).parents('form.entertournament')` and see if it works.

Comment: Or  you can do the following: add an ID to the form like `<form id="tournament-{{$tournament->id}}">`; the add an attribute in button `<button data-form_id="tournament-{{$tournament->id}}">`. and lastly in your js change this line `$(this).closest('form');` to `let form = $("#" + $(this).attr("data-form_id"));`

Comment: add attribute <button type="button">

Comment: Just `$('.entertournament').on('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault() ... });`. `let form = $(this)` and add `type="submit"` to the button.

Comment: I have tried both the solutions suggest by Sainesh but redirect is still occurring. On each occasion I get redirected to /enterTournament and a 419 error or a JSON response is returned depending on if I include @csrf under the form. 

Adding attribute type="button" does nothing - I am not redirected but nothing is posted either, no errors or messages returned in console.

Thanks for all the suggestions so far, hopefully I or someone can come up with a solution soon. :)

Comment: Hi azeós, thanks for the suggestion. Output is still the same with your solution - form placed outside the table is also now redirecting and displaying the JSON.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `ajax` call? It sills redirects? If not, then there's something wrong in the `success()`.

Comment: If I remove the Javascript used to submit the form the redirect is still occurring.

Comment: You probably have javascript code somewhere else. Or... do you have javascript disabled?

Comment: Yes you are correct, the table is being rendered with javascript which was causing the problems!